# Loop through rows and compare values in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

How would I go about looping through a row of values to see whether or not the row is a duplicate of another row, and then remove the duplicate? For example, in the below screenshot the duplicate rows would be 1 & 8, 2 & 9. I would want to keep 1 and 2 and just remove rows 8 and 9.

[image]

Comment: Go to the Data tab and use Remove Duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Remove Duplicates` within the tool bar at the top of excel, this allows you to remove duplicate entries but keep the first record found. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) for more information.